# Force update of the Outlook object model from pending user input

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office365, vsto

I'm developing an Outlook Add-In which relies on the data the user enters into the Location field on an appointment.
If the user enters data into that field and clicks a button of my Add-In, the value of AppointmentItem.Location still contains the old value. Only after clicking the button again the new value the user entered is present in AppointmentItem.Location.

(If the user leaves the field before pressing the button, e.g. by focusing the body field, the new value is written to AppointmentItem.Location.)

How do I tell outlook to process the user input and commit the new data into the AppointmentItem.Location field before continuing with my code that relies on that field value? Or is there another way to get the latest user input?

I'm using Outlook 2016, while developing a VSTO Add-In with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Have you checked this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-updating-the-controls-on-a-ribbon-at-run-time?view=vs-2017